# CSS has no effect on dynamic classes

Tags: jquery, css, addclass, effect

```
$('fieldset.one label, fieldset.two label').each(function () {
    var className = $(this).text().trim().toLowerCase();
    $(this).addClass('default ' + className);
});
```

I'm adding classes dynamically to label elements, but when I try to style them, there is no effect. One of them has .sedan class added automatically, I see it in firebug, but the following doesn't have any effect:

```
.sedan {
  display:none !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<fieldset class="one">
  <label>sedan</label>
  <label>suv</label>
  <label>truck</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="two">
  <label>sedan</label>
  <label>suv</label>
  <label>truck</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Please include the html being targeted.

Comment: That's not `<fieldset class="one">`.  How about showing the actual HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`trim`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.trim) method:

```
var className = $.trim($(this).text()).toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted, the original code supplied will only work in recent versions of Firefox that actually implement the Javascript 1.8.1 `String.trim()` method.

Comment: Ah, what was downvoted (by someone) is actually the solution! :)

Comment: Yes, but it was failing in Chrome (mac) and Firefox (mac)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted here. I just tested it locally and it works just fine. Make sure your selectors are correct - and you can check to see whether the styles are being added with firebug.

Comment: There's a space after "default", and jQuery splits on spaces. OP's code should add two different classes to each element.

Comment: OP's code *does* add two classes (given what was posted here).

Answer (score 0):

Works for me: http://jsbin.com/amovo/edit